# Moving old wordpress.com site stats to a self hosted blog

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs, jetpack

I recently moved my old wordpress.com blog into self hosted blog with a my own domain name. So far I have done these things.

1. transferred my old articles and posts.
2. installed and activated the Jetpack plugin.
3. transferred my old blog followers with the help of wordpress support team.

And now I want to get transfer my old blog site stats into new one. Is it possible to do so? At least is there a work around for that?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, albeit not too in-depth, the vast majority of results seems to point to this not being possible.

Please see -> [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-transfer-stats-between-blogs) <- for more information.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help :) . but it doesn't says a way to transfer stats :(

Answer (score 0):

Personally I do not use Jetpack for stats but digging into jetpack it seems that the stats are transferred based on the domain name.

Reference:

http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/moving-jetpacked-wporg-installation-to-another-site

So technically as long as you have the same mysite.com address it should retain the stats.

As for transferring wordpress over to your own server, I have done this a couple times and the one that seems to work the best for me is this process.

From Old Server:

```
Export MySQL database

Copy the whole file directory
```

From new Server:

```
Install a copy of Wordpress on your server (just to create the DB and file structure)

Empty the newly created MySQL DB and import the database from the Old Server.

Copy/Replace all files from the old server to the new one except for wp-config.php (since it has new credentials)

Lastly I go into wp-admin -> Settings and save the permalinks to have it resetup the .htaccess
```

Hope this helps.